# Lining up content in divs without table cells

Tags: html, css, tabular

I have two rows of links like:

```
Link 1     Link 2     Link 3     Link 4
Link 5     Link 6     Link 7     LInk 8
```

I need the top four links to align with the top bottom links regardless of how many characters are in the link.  For example,

```
This is link 1     This is link 2            Link 3     L4
LInk 1             Link 2 that is longer     Link 3     L4
```

I can do this with tables and td cells but how can this be accomplished just using divs?

Answer (score 3):

```
<ul id="links">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#links {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#links li {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This will work if he puts a link-list in each div and arranges the div's side by side.

Comment: There is no need to use a div. Divs are dividers, not lists. ul's are better suited for this as they are more semantically correct (he has _list_ of links). The float: left, and width: 50%, will cause the behavior that he wants.

Comment: OP should be aware that he should not add borders or padding with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

By just styling divs with `display: inline-block;` you can get the alignment you want.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div><a>This is link 1</a></div><div><a>This is link 2</a></div><div><a>Link 3</a></div><div><a>L4</a></div>
<div><a>LInk 1</a></div><div><a>Link 2 that is longer</a></div><div><a>Link 3</a></div><div><a>L4</a></div>
```

### Note 1:

There are no spaces between the divs of a line. That is intentional. It is a quirk of `display: inline-block;`. Adding spaces will brake the layout. If you have to have spaces between divs then a usual solution is to apply a negative margin:

`margin: 0px -4px;`

### Note 2:

Divs should not have any other paddings or margins. Otherwise the layout will break.